# "Eval in REPL" command not doing anything for Scheme in SublimeREPL

Tags: scheme, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I'm attempting to use SublimeREPL with Sublime Text 2 as a Scheme environment.  I have Gauche installed and can successfully launch a REPL window and run code from it.  However, I can't figure out how to use the "Eval in REPL" or "Transfer to REPL" commands in the plugin.

When I execute the command (either by shortcut or from the menu) I can see in the console that the command is being run, but it doesn't actually do anything.  This is regardless of whether I have a REPL window opened already or not.  I suspect it's not able to figure out which external id it's supposed to be using, but not sure how to fix that.

Comment: what platform are you on?  Windows, OS X, Linux?  What version?  (and is it 32- or 64-bit?)

Comment: Sorry, I'm on Windows 7 64-bit, with the 32-bit version of Gauche installed.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me on Linux using Sublime 2.0.2 and the following Sublime packages:

- SublimeREPL 2.1.1
- Gauche 2013.04.16.05.32.34
- Scheme 2013.03.04.21.30.59

Note that these are Sublime packages installable through Package Control: you also need to have the real Gauche interpreter installed on the local system.

I needed to restart several times.  Save your Gauche code as a .scm file and switch the buffer to Gauche mode.  Use Tools > SublimeREPL > Scheme > Gauche to start the REPL and you should be able to freely eval and transfer expressions from the buffer in Gauche mode to the REPL.